# Dynamic creation of an expression query for getting data from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, expression, iqueryable

I want to create a query of type `Expression` that gets some columns of an entity from Entity Framework.

Assume we have two classes like this:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Child MyChild { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And we have an `IQueryable` list of `Parent`:

```
var q = new List<Parent>()
{
    new Parent {Id = 1, Name = "a", Number = 1, MyChild=new Child{Id=11,Name="Child_a",Number=2}},
    new Parent {Id = 2, Name = "b", Number = 1, MyChild=new Child{Id=22,Name="Child_b",Number=2}},
    new Parent {Id = 3, Name = "c", Number = 1, MyChild=new Child{Id=33,Name="Child_c",Number=2}},
}.AsQueryable();
```

I want to get a list of those properties of `q` that user determines them. For example user determines that he needs `Parent.Name` and `Parent.MyChils.Name`. So I should give the user a list of anonymous type like this:

```
{"a","Child_a"}
{"b","Child_b"}
{"c","Child_c"}
```

If the `Parent` entity doesn't contain any foreign key property (in this example `MyChild` property) it is so easy to create an expression property that takes some properties of `Parent` dynamically. I have a code that gets some properties of `Person` without `MyChild` property of it:

```
var columns = new List<string> { "Id", "Name" };
var xParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Parent), "x");
var sourceProperties = columns.ToDictionary(name => name,
    name => q.ElementType.GetProperty(name));
var dynamicType = LinqRuntimeTypeBuilder.GetDynamicType(sourceProperties.Values);
var bindings =
    dynamicType.GetFields()
        .Select(p => Expression.Bind(p, Expression.Property(xParam, sourceProperties[p.Name])))
        .OfType<MemberBinding>();
var newExpr = Expression.New(dynamicType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
Expression selector = Expression.Lambda(Expression.MemberInit(
    Expression.New(dynamicType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)), bindings), xParam);
var body = Expression.MemberInit(newExpr, bindings);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Parent, dynamic>>(body, xParam);
var t = q.Select(lambda);
```

(2 used methods are here:)

```
public static Type GetDynamicType2(Dictionary<string, Type> fields)
{
    if (null == fields)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("fields");
    if (0 == fields.Count)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("fields", "fields must have at least 1 field definition");
    try
    {
        Monitor.Enter(builtTypes);
        string className = "MyDynamicType";
        if (builtTypes.ContainsKey(className))
            return builtTypes[className];
        TypeBuilder typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType(className,
            TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.Serializable);
        foreach (var field in fields)
            typeBuilder.DefineField(field.Key, field.Value, FieldAttributes.Public);
        builtTypes[className] = typeBuilder.CreateType();
        return builtTypes[className];
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(builtTypes);
    }

    return null;
}

public static Type GetDynamicType(IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> fields)
{
    return GetDynamicType(fields.ToDictionary(f => f.Name, f => f.PropertyType));
}
```

But still I can't get internal properties of `MyChild` property of `Parent`.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody answered my question I tried many different ways to solve it, upshot problem solved utilizing recursive creation of `Expression`.
For every property of type `Class` (like `MyChild` in the question) we most create an `Expression`. Creation of `Expressions` most be recursive like this:

```
    private Expression BuildExpression(Expression parentExpression,
        Type parentPropertyType, string pathOfChildProperty)
    {
        string remainPathOfChild;
        var childPropertyName = 
              GetFirstPropertyNameFromPathAndRemainPath(pathOfChildProperty, out remainPathOfChild);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(childPropertyName)) return parentExpression;
        var childPropInfo = parentPropertyType.GetProperty(childPropertyName);
        var childExpression = Expression.Property(parentExpression, childPropInfo);
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(remainPathOfChild)
            ? BuildExpressionForInternalProperty(childExpression, childPropInfo.PropertyType, remainPathOfChild)
            : childExpression;
    }
    private string GetFirstPropertyNameFromPathAndRemainPath(string path, out string remainPath)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            remainPath = null;
            return null;
        }
        var indexOfDot = path.IndexOf('.');
        if (indexOfDot < 0)
        {
            remainPath = null;
            return path;
        }
        remainPath = path.Substring(indexOfDot + 1);
        return path.Substring(0, indexOfDot);
    }
    }
```

Recursive call will stop when remain path of internal property be empty.
In highest level the calling of this method is like this:

```
var inputParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(GrandParent), "x");
var expChildProperty = 
    BuildExpression(inputParameter,typeof(Parent),"Parent.MyChils.Name");
```

Finally result expression for above problem is `(($x.Parent).MyChils).Name` in debug view.